# .Net Linq to JSON with Newtonsoft JSON library

Tags: .net, json, linq, json.net

I have some JSON that is sent to my webservice that looks something like this.

```
{
    root: [
        {
            "key": "foo1",
            "val": "150"
        },
        {
            "key": "foo2",
            "val": "220"
        },
        {
            "key": "foo3",
            "val": "300"
        },
        {
            "key": "dataid",
            "val": "2289"
        }
    ]
}
```

Say I wanted to return the value of `val` where `key` is equal to `"dataid"`. How would I do this using the [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/default.aspx) library?

I know I can loop through the values to find it but it is likely that the object will be far bigger than this example here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CodeInChaos - yep, they are.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well *something* is going to have to loop through at some point. If you need to fetch lots of values by key from the same JSON, you should probably build a `Dictionary<string, string>` from it - which means looping over it once (either explicitly or using the LINQ `ToDictionary` method) but then having fast access afterwards.

Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(text);
        JArray root = (JArray) obj["root"];

        var dictionary = root.ToDictionary(x => (string) x["key"],
                                           x => (string) x["val"]);

        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["dataid"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Jon beat me to it, but here's another way of doing it:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

var item = jobject.Property("root")
                  .Values()
                  .Single(x => x.Value<string>("key") == "foo1");

var value = item.Value<string>("val");

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Slightly more LINQ-y, but there's no way of really getting rid of the magic strings if you use LINQ to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the more LINQ-y answer Dan:)