# How to convert json to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, json

How could you convert a string of JSON to a C# `NameValueCollection` simply, preferably without using a 3rd party parser?

Comment: Check the util class from this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571168/what-json-library-works-well-for-you-in-net

Comment: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why everyone is still recommending JSON.NET for deserialization of JSON. I wrote a [blog post on how to deserialize JSON to C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c/).

In short, it's like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonText);

NameValueCollection nvc = null;
if (dict != null) {
  nvc = new NameValueCollection(dict.Count);
  foreach (var k in dict) {
    nvc.Add(k.Key, k.Value);
  }
}
                    }
var json = jss.Serialize(dict);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Be sure to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.dll.

**Note:**
I usually deserialize to `dynamic`, so I'm assuming that `NameValueCollection` would work. However, I haven't verified if it actually does.

Comment: Hi, this looks great, I tried this which I wrote from yours:

    `public static NameValueCollection JSONToNVC(string json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss;
        NameValueCollection nvc;

        jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        nvc = new NameValueCollection();

        try
        {
            nvc = jss.Deserialize<NameValueCollection>(json);
        }
        catch
        {
             
        }

        return nvc;
    }`

with `{"status":"error","message":"Key could not be given","key":""}` but `nvc` always ends up empty, can you spot what's wrong?

Comment: @James You are right, the original post simply does not work. Many thanks to JP Richardson for the post AND excellent blog, there is only Dictionary => NameValueCollection transformation still needed, but this is the way to go.

Comment: It must be noted that the author of that blog, as of 20130325, has changed his opinion of third party JSON libraries, and in fact calls this method "outdated" in the referenced post. While not endorsing the industry standard library, he has written his own and prefers it to native .NET JSON support.

Comment: I'm author of the blog post and this answer. I should add an addendum of clarity to your note. This method presented here is the recommended way. I lacked context in my statement of calling this method "outdated". I actually shouldn't have even included that statement at all, and should remove it.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

Pure .net solution without third party development have look : [JavaScriptSerializer – Dictionary to JSON Serialization and Deserialization](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/07/23/javascriptserializer-dictionary-to-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx)

---

make use of [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json)

```
string jsonstring = @"{""keyabc"":""valueabc"",""keyxyz"":""valuexyz""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonstring);
```

Check @jon answer suggest same : [.Net Linq to JSON with Newtonsoft JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033178/net-linq-to-json-with-newtonsoft-json-library)

Comment: He specifically say she does not want to use a third party parser.  However, the suggestion of JSON.NET is still good, because it's a ubiquitous library that solves all sorts of problems that .net developers routinely have.

Comment: @Jodrell - its free you can visite the link

Comment: @PranayRana Many, many companies have a lot of restrictions on what may or may not be used in their production products.  Many banks, for example, will require that all open-source solutions go through a review for licensing entanglements, security, etc.  These processes can take weeks or months, and he may not have that kind of time!

Comment: I know but, it is a third party library.

Comment: Json.NET is included in later versions of .NET, so it is no longer a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON contains nested objects whithin it the solution below will handle them properly (based on JSON.NET, but you can adapt to the JSON parser of your choice).

This usage example:

```
var json = "{\"status\":\"paid\",\"date\":\"2019-10-09T17:30:51.479Z\",\"customer\":{\"id\":123456789,\"country\":\"br\",\"name\":\"Thomas Vilhena\",\"phone_numbers\":[\"+5511987654321\"],\"documents\":[{\"id\":\"doc_id\"}]}}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);            
var nvc = new NameValueCollection(dict.Count);
AddKeyValuePairs(nvc, dict);

Console.WriteLine(nvc["status"]);
Console.WriteLine(nvc["date"]);
Console.WriteLine(nvc["customer[phone_numbers][0]"]);
Console.WriteLine(nvc["customer[id]"]);
Console.WriteLine(nvc["customer[documents][0][id]"]);
```

Produces the following output:

```
paid
09.10.2019 17:30
+5511987654321
123456789
doc_id
```

And here's the implementation:

```
private static void AddKeyValuePairs(
    NameValueCollection nvc,
    Dictionary<string, object> dict,
    string prefix = null)
{
    foreach (var k in dict)
    {
        var key = prefix == null ? k.Key : prefix + "[" + k.Key + "]";
        if (k.Value != null)
            AddKeyValuePair(nvc, key, k.Value);
    }
}

private static void AddKeyValuePair(
    NameValueCollection nvc,
    string key,
    object value)
{
    if (value is string || value.GetType().IsPrimitive)
    {
        nvc.Add(key, value.ToString());
    }
    else if (value is DateTime)
    {
        nvc.Add(key, ((DateTime)value).ToString("g"));
    }
    else
    {
        AddNonPrimitiveValue(nvc, key, value);
    }
}

private static void AddNonPrimitiveValue(
    NameValueCollection nvc,
    string key,
    object value)
{
    var a = value as JArray;
    if (a != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            AddKeyValuePair(nvc, key + "[" + i + "]", a[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        var v = value as JValue;
        if (v != null)
        {
            AddKeyValuePair(nvc, key, v.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var j = value as JObject;
            if (j != null)
                AddKeyValuePairs(nvc, j.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(), key);
        }
    }
}
```