# How can I convert json string (complex object) to NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I want to convert a json string to NameValueCollection. I came up with the code below.

```
public static NameValueCollection ConvertFromJson(string json)
{
    var anonymous = JContainer.Parse(json);          

    var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(anonymous);

    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == null)
        {
            // I am OK if a property is null. Just skip it.
            continue;
        }

        if (kvp.Value.GetType().Name.Contains("Anonymous"))
        {
            var prefix = kvp.Key + ".";
            foreach (var innerkvp in new RouteValueDictionary(kvp.Value))
            {
                nvc.Add(prefix + innerkvp.Key, innerkvp.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nvc.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    return nvc;
}
```

It works well with normal classes but not nested classes. For example, it works with `class A` but not `class B`.

```
class A
{
    public string AAA { get; set; }
    public int BBB { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string AAA { get; set; }
    public MyOtherClass BBB { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert nested objects to NameValueCollection?

**Explain**
This question is absolutely not duplicate with [How to convert json to NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398882/how-to-convert-json-to-namevaluecollection). The answer in that question only works with `class A` but it does not work with `class B`.

Comment: How would you like to represent `MyOtherClass` as a string?

Comment: @BenRobinson to be frank, I don't know. I want to serialize and deserialize it. Is there a way, for example, some interfaces that I need to implement to make it works?

Comment: I can't share my code, but you seriously need to look at Json.NET. It fully supports parsing json the way you've described.

Comment: @code4life thanks. I am looking into it now.

Comment: @code4life Do you mean JsonConvert? If so, it doesn't work with the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

If you only whant to serialise/deserialise a nested object like you shared on the question you could use a work around like this:

`Dictionary <string, object> deserializedresult = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);`

The only problem with it that you need to serialise and desrialise again the nested objects or use reflection to reach the contained elements of the nested objects.